# componentWillReceiveProps not triggering from child screen inside Tabview

Tags: react-native

I'm new in React native here. I got stuck on this scenario. I have a Dashboard screen. Inside dashboard screen, there's Hitcher screen that has Tabview. And there are HitcherTrip and HitcherChat inside the Tabview. In HitcherTrip, i expected componentWillReceiveProps() will trigger after calling Actions.goToOtherLayout() but componentWillReceiveProps() is triggered on Dashboard screen (Parent screen).

1. Dashboard

   ```
   const Menu = createDrawerNavigator(
       {
         First: { screen: Hitcher },
         Second: { screen: Driver }
       },
       {
         contentComponent: props => (
           <ScrollView>
               <View style={{ padding:20, backgroundColor:'#4ca858' }}>
                   <Image source={require('../assets/pp.png')} style={{ borderRadius: 40, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#fff',width:80, height: 80 }} />
                   <CustomDrawerText/>
               </View>
               <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never" }}>
                   <Drawer.Item
                       label="I am Hitcher"
                       style={styles.drawerItem}
                       onPress={
                           () => {}
                       }
                   />
                   <View style={{ height:1, backgroundColor:'#a8a8a8', marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}/>
                   <Drawer.Item
                       label="I am Driver"
                       onPress={
                           () => {}
                       }
                       style={styles.drawerItem}
                   />
                   <View style={{ height:1, backgroundColor:'#a8a8a8', marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}/>
                   <Drawer.Item
                       label="Settings"
                       style={styles.drawerItem}
                   />
                   <View style={{ height:1, backgroundColor:'#a8a8a8', marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}/>
                   <Drawer.Item
                       label="Log Out"
                       style={styles.drawerItem}
                       onPress={
                           () => {}
                       }
                   />
                   <View style={{ height:1, backgroundColor:'#a8a8a8', marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}/>
               </SafeAreaView>
           </ScrollView>
         )
       }
   );

   const AppNav = createAppContainer(Menu);

   export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {

       constructor(props) {
           super(props)
       }

       componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
           console.log("Dashboard");
       }

       render() {
           return( 
               <AppNav />
           )
       }
   }
   ```
2. Hitcher

   ```
   export default class Hitcher extends React.Component {
       state = {
           index: 0,
           routes: [
             { key: 'first', title: 'My Trips' },
             { key: 'second', title: 'Chats' },
           ],
       };

       async _storeItem(key, token) {
           try {
               var token = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, token);
               return token;
           } catch (error) {
             console.log(error.message);
           }
       }

       render() {
         return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
               <Appbar.Header
                   style={{ backgroundColor: '#4ca858' }}>
                   <Appbar.Action
                       icon="menu"
                       color="white"
                       onPress={() =>
                           this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())
                       }
                   />
                   <Appbar.Action icon={require('../assets/logo_inverted.png')} style={{flex:1, alignSelf:'center'}} size={65} color="white"/>

                   <Appbar.Action icon="bell" color="white"/>
               </Appbar.Header>
               <View style={styles.container}>
                   <TabView
                       style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                       navigationState={this.state}
                       renderScene={SceneMap({
                           first: HitcherTrip,
                           second: HitcherChat,
                       })}
                       renderTabBar={props =>
                           <TabBar
                               {...props}
                               labelStyle={styles.label}
                               indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
                               style={styles.tabbar}
                               getLabelText={({ route }) => route.title}
                           />
                       }
                       onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })} />
               </View>
           </View>
         );
       }
   }
   ```
3. HitcherTrip

   ```
   export default class HitcherTrip extends React.Component {

       constructor(props) {
           super(props);

           this.state = {
               data: [],
               isFetching: false,
               spinner: false,
               itemId: 0
           };
       }

       componentDidMount() {
           this.getTrips();
       }

       getTrips = () => {
           // codes
       };

       componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
           console.log("HitcherTrip");
       }

       onRefresh() {
           this.setState({isFetching: true,},() => {this.getTrips();});
       }

       createTrip = () => {
           Actions.goToOtherLayout();
       };

       render() {
           return(
               <View style={styles.scene} >
                   <FlatList
                       showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                       data={this.state.data}
                       renderItem={({item}) => {
                           var date = Moment(item.created_at).format('DD MMM');
                           var now = Moment();
                           var expired = Moment(item.expired_at);
                           var status = item.status_name;
                           if (now > expired && item.status == 0)
                               status = "Expired";
                           return (
                               <TouchableOpacity onPress={
                                   () => {
                                   }
                               }>
                                   <Spinner
                                       visible={this.state.spinner}
                                       textContent={'Loading...'}
                                       textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
                                   />
                                   <View style={styles.container}>
                                       {item.status == 0 ?
                                           <View style={styles.header}>
                                               <Text style={styles.headerLeftActive}>{status}</Text>
                                               <Text style={styles.headerRightActive}>{item.request_no}</Text>
                                           </View> : 
                                           <View style={styles.headerInActive}>
                                               <Text style={styles.headerLeftInactive}>{status}</Text>
                                               <Text style={styles.headerRightInactive}>{date}</Text>
                                           </View>
                                       }
                                       <View style={styles.content}>
                                           <Image source={require('../assets/fromto.png')} style={styles.image} />
                                           <View style={styles.textContent}>
                                               <Text style={styles.address}>{item.pickup_location}</Text>
                                               <View style={{flex: 1}} />
                                               <Text style={styles.address}>{item.dropoff_location}</Text>
                                           </View>
                                       </View>
                                   </View>
                               </TouchableOpacity>
                           )}
                       }
                       keyExtractor={item => item.request_no}
                       onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
                       refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
                   /> 

                   <TouchableOpacity
                       style={{
                           alignItems:'center',
                           justifyContent:'center',
                           width:70,
                           position: 'absolute',                                          
                           bottom: 10,                                                    
                           right: 10,
                           height:70,
                           backgroundColor:'#4ca858',
                           borderRadius:100,
                           elevation: 6, 
                       }} onPress={this.createTrip}>
                       <Text style={{color:'#fff', fontSize: 32}}>+</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity>
               </View>
           )
       }
   }
   ```

On other layout, i have set

```
Actions.pop(); setTimeout(()=> Actions.refresh(), 500);
```

to trigger componentWillReceiveProps() when press back button. But it only triggers on Dashboard screen.

How to trigger componentWillReceiveProps() on HitcherTrip? Or maybe trigger HitcherTrip function from Dashboard screen?